# How to prove that $\|x\|_s\le n^{(r-s)/(rs)}\|x\|_r$ if $s \le r$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have to prove that $\mathbf{(1)}$ $\|x\|_s\le n^{(r-s)/(rs)}\|x\|_r$ and $\mathbf{(2)}$ $\|x\|_s\le n^{1/s}\|x\|_{\infty}$ if $1\le s \le r\le \infty$. Unless I'm considering this wrong, the only nontrivial case is when $1<p <q<\infty$. I've been looking for this excersize, and haven't found it, so here is what I've done so far.

 For $\mathbf{(1)}$, I apply the Hölder's inequality to $\mathbf x=(|x_1|^s,\dots,|x_n|^s)$ and $\mathbf y=(1,\dots,1)$, and as a hint we have to take $p=r/(r-s)$ and $q=r/s$ (so $1/p + 1/q =1$):
$$\large \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k*1|=\sum_{k=1}^n |x_k| \le \left( \sum_{k=1}^n 1^{r/(r-s)}\right)^{(r-s)/r} \left( \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^{r/s}\right)^{s/r} = n^{(r-s)/r}\left( \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^{r/s}\right)^{s/r}$$
So I got something tha looks like what i want, but for some reason i can't get to it from here. I feel something's missing.

 On the other hand,for $\mathbf{(2)}$, I have the feeling that is a particular case from $\mathbf{(1)}$, I thougth maybe when $r\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: You're almost there; try replacing $x_k$ with $x_k^s$. 

And your intuition about (2) will work.

Comment: You might also like to consider (2) from the perspective that each $x_k$ is less than the number $\|x\|_\infty$. Without even knowing Hoelder's inequality, how would you bound $\sum |x_k|^s$? This may give you some intuition about $\ell^\infty$ norms that the other approach doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you may use Hölder inequality, but in your calculations (remember, you apply the inequality to $(x_1^s,\dots,x_n^s)$) you should have
$$
\sum |x_k|^s \leq n^{\frac{r-s}{r}} \left(\sum |x_k|^r \right)^{s/r}.
$$
Now just take the $1/s$-power of both sides.

To prove your second claim, observe that
$$
\left( \sum |x_k|^s \right)^{1/s} \leq \left( \sum (\max_k|x_k|)^s \right)^{1/s} = \|x\|_\infty \left( \sum 1 \right)^{1/s} = \| x \|_\infty n^{1/s}.
$$